# Regex to get HTML elements and attributes

Tags: php, html, regex, dom

I'm very new at regular expressions: I want to preg_match all elements in a html dom, that has a data-editable attribute. All other attributes of those elements should be matched also, so i can reuse them later:

```
<div class="teaser" id="teaser" data-editable><p>Content</p></div>
```

After matching i want those elements with data-editable attribute to have specific css classes and add another element inside. So only block-level parents should be matched.

```
<div class="teaser editable" id="teaser"><button>edit</button><p>Content</p></div>
```

Here's what i've got:

```
<(div|p).*(data-editable).[^>]+>(.*?)<\/\1>
```

I know, i'm totally wrong with that - this one matches also elements that does not have that data-editable attribute set because of that `.+` inside. But how to match the different attributes without losing their values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't go through HTML with regex (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)). What you should do would be to use an HTML parsing framework, such as the [PHP Simple DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to process your HTML pages.

According to their documentation, you can do what you want through this: `$html->find("div[data-editable]", 0)->outertext`

Answer (score 0):

Since HTML isn't a regular language, you're better of using a DOM parser. Much easier, too